# Trying to use sqlite with python shell

Tags: python, sqlite

I just got python and typing:

```
sqlite test.db
```

into the shell, but I get a syntax error. What have I missed?

Comment: I think you missed reading the documentation, especially the Python language tutorial.  Try that first.

Comment: sqlite test.db is valid command in cmd or terminal not in python shell

Answer (score 8):

I guess that you did the following?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sqlite test.db
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sqlite test.db
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Try this instead:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''Your query goes here''')
```

For more details, take a look at the sqlite documentation for [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) or [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't provide this command-line utility so make sure [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) is in your path. Then you can either execute:

```
$ sqlite3 mydb.db
```

or if you have entered your settings in **settings.py**:

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify if sqlite exist in `PATH` and what are privileges for file `test.db`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want  to use the sqlite3 command line tool to create a new database. For this you should use your system terminal not the python console. So the command should look like so (on a linux system):

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
```